# Assembly Language parsing in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, debugging, assembly, syntax

I implement a regex code in c#.

but, it is too difficult to read.
and I couldn't capture syntax....

```
// tests
Regex identifier = new Regex("^[^0-9\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
    "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
    "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ][^\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
    "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
    "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ]*");                              // _1234asdvvf or asdfvasdf (0asdfasdf -> X)

Regex number16  = new Regex("^([0][x][0-9A-Fa-f]*|[0-9a-fA-F]*[h])"); // 0xABCD or ABCDh
Regex number10  = new Regex("^[1-9][0-9]*");                          // 123456  (01234 -> X)
Regex number8   = new Regex("^[0][0-9]*");                            // 012345
Regex string_   = new Regex("^[\"]([^\"\r\n]|[\\][\"])*[\"]");        // "asdfkawer\"asdf\"asdfasdf"
Regex char_     = new Regex("^[\']([^\'\r\n]|[\\][\'])*[\']");        // 'asdfasdf\'asdfasdf\'asdfadf'
Regex boolean   = new Regex("^(true|false)");                           // true or false
Regex floating  = new Regex("^([0]|[1-9][0-9]*)\\.[0-9]*[eE]?[\\+\\-]?[0-9]*[f]?"); // 1234.1234e-45123 or 0.123411234e+1234, 123.1234123e10
Regex limiter   = new Regex("^(public|private|protected|internal)");
Regex impls     = new Regex("^(extern|static|virtual|abstract)");
Regex whitespace= new Regex("^[\t\r\n ]*");
Regex operaters = new Regex("^[\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
    "\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
    "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\-]");

// implements
Regex assemblyRegex = new Regex("^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\t ]*" + // Opcode + Whitespace

    "((" + // without Comma + Identifier or Numbers or String
        "[^0-9\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
        "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
        "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ][^\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
        "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
        "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ]*" + // Identifier

        "|" + // OR

        "([0][x][0-9A-Fa-f]*|[0-9a-fA-F]*[h])" + // Hexa number

        "|" + // OR

        "[1-9][0-9]*" + // Decimal

        "|" + // OR

        "[\"]([^\"\r\n]|[\\][\"])*[\"]" + // String
    ")" + // generic cases
    "|" + // OR
        "(qword|dword|word|byte)?[\\[]" +   // qword [
    // Comma + Identifier or Numbers
            "(([^0-9\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
            "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
            "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ][^\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
            "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
            "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ]*" + // Identifier

            "|" + // OR

            "([0][x][0-9A-Fa-f]*|[0-9a-fA-F]*[h])" + // Hexa number

            "|" + // OR

            "[1-9][0-9]*)" + // Decimal

            "[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\%]?)*" + // Operators

        "[\\]]" +                           // ]
    ")[\t ]*" + // DEST

    "([\\,][\t ]*((" + // Comma + Identifier or Numbers or String
        "[^0-9\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
        "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
        "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ][^\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
        "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
        "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ]*" + // Identifier

        "|" + // OR

        "([0][x][0-9A-Fa-f]*|[0-9a-fA-F]*[h])" + // Hexa number

        "|" + // OR

        "[1-9][0-9]*" + // Decimal

        "|" + // OR

        "[\"]([^\"\r\n]|[\\][\"])*[\"]" + // String
    ")" + // generic cases
    "|" + // OR
        "(qword|dword|word|byte)?[\\[]" +   // qword [
            // Comma + Identifier or Numbers
            "(([^0-9\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
            "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
            "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ][^\t\r\n\\~\\!\\@\\#\\" +
            "\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\|\\\\\\[\\]\\{\\}\\:\\;" +
            "\\'\\\"\\<\\>\\/\\?\\.\\,\\`\\- ]*" + // Identifier

            "|" + // OR

            "([0][x][0-9A-Fa-f]*|[0-9a-fA-F]*[h])" + // Hexa number

            "|" + // OR

            "[1-9][0-9]*)" + // Decimal

            "[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\%]?)*" + // Operators

        "[\\]]" +                           // ]
    "))*" + // SRCS

    "[\r\n]?" + // end of line.
    "|" + // OR

    "[\r\n\t ]" + // whitespace only.
    "|" + // OR

    "[\\;][^\r\n]*[\r\n])*"); // comment line.


Match match = assemblyRegex.Match("mov eax, 0xabcd\njmp abcdef\ncmp eax, ebx\ncmp a, b");
```

how can I capture words from the code...
and, how can I debug regex codes....

(this is not for developing something, just my hobby @_@)

I want to get the result like => `string[] { "mov", "eax", ",", "qword", "[", "esp", "+", "8", "]" }`.
but, this code only works to verify the syntax;; (but, `repz cmp a, b` couldn't be recognized...)
aka, That was my intention and another code. I do not know where to fix it.

1. Is there a way to debug regex more easily?
2. Or is there a way to extract the tokens?
3. Or is there a way to write regex more simple?

Comment: Have you try https://regex101.com ?

Comment: Regex analyzer? Have a look at Expresso, it is written on .NET which means it uses .NET Regex implementation: http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Comment: Maybe a grammar would fit better?

Comment: @jayk: Expresso is free to use. The "license" is totally free. I have been using it for more than 7 years. Didn't pay a kopeck / grosz / etc.

Comment: shouldn't you try to use some kind of lexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to *"Is there an way to write regex more simple?"*:

Use literal c# strings, prefixed with @. Backslashes are taken literally inside such strings. Double quotes are inserted by a double-double quote. The following are equivalent strings: `"\\'\\\"\\<\\>"` and `@"\'\""\<\>"`.

You are also escaping many characters that are unnecessary, especially inside character classes, only complicating the regex.  Many characters are only interpreted as meta-characters in particular constructs.  Other tools, like Expresso that is mentioned in comments, can help more easily identify what characters need escaping.

For instance, the previous strings inside a characters class can be as simple as `@"['""<>]"`, no escapes needed. This also makes it much easier copying from/into other tools.  You must still be aware of the double quotes when copying back and forth between other tools, but in the particular string I shared it should not matter since it doesn't hurt to have a character specified twice in a character class.

In answer to *"is there a way to extract the tokens?"*:

By default, a set of parenthesis captures the matched texted in numbered groups.  .Net regex also supports named capture groups, like `(?<grpName>pattern)`.  You access them via the Match.Group property, like `match.Group["grpName"]`.